# Stubing google places call selenium vs capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, capybara-webkit, webmock

I am using **Capybara** with **selenium** AND/OR **capybara-webkit** driver and Webmock as a stubbing framework.

When I run my integration tests for google maps (places) autocomplete input using selenium (firefox) the browser makes a few real calls to google and receives JSONs with the place components.

When I change to capybara-webkit driver (muuuuch faster) to do the same I get webmock message that I should stub an external requests.

Can someone please explain me why there's difference between the two?

Note: I set `WebMock.disable_net_connect!( :allow_localhost => true )` to allow calls to the local server...

EDIT:

> Tools like WebMock are great, but when testing JavaScript, it’s a
>   seperate browser process that loads the page, and not your Ruby test
>   process. That means that the request to your build server isn’t going
>   through Net::HTTP; the requests are coming from Firefox or
>   capybara-webkit, and those tools are gleefully unaware of your feeble
>   attempts to reroute HTTP traffic

quote from http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-capybara-to-test-javascript-that-makes-http

This explains why some calls to a payment system (done in the Rails controller) need to be stubbed and why ajax doesn't, but it doesn't explain why Firefox reaches Google and webkit asks for a stub

SOLUTION:

**TL;DR;** keep :selenium and make a real call in tests that need to make ajax call to external APIs

I tried mocking with puffing-billy that is used for JS/browser external calls, but this one doesn't "cooperate well" with Webmock. Also I have like 25 stubs for the payment system alredy written in Webmock so no way I am switching...

I also tried VRC which is recording framework, but this one is also for calls made by your application (Ruby NET library)

In the end I simply decided to keep running these couple of tests that need ajax API responses using :selenium driver which starts firefox and makes a real call to gMaps

```
#spec_helper
...
WebMock.disable_net_connect!( :allow_localhost => true )   # Ask to stub all requests except to localhost
...

# Use headless capybara-webkit that is way faster!
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
config.before(:each, js: true) do
   ...
end

# And when you need :selenium and firefox mark the spec with :force_selenium => true
config.before(:each, force_selenium: true) do
   Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are risen not from `webmock`, but from `capybara-webkit` itself, and it wishes you to declare the behaviour for access to a host explicitly like follows:

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|                                      
   config.allow_url("fonts.googleapis.com")
   config.allow_url("www.sandbox.paypal.com")
   config.allow_url("altfarm.mediaplex.com")
end
```